# Vaildation in Custom components in angular reactive form not working

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create a new component in angular reactive forms.
Here is my sample project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pyi9jn

I have created a very simple angular form of this architecture:

form
 - simple counter

The output of form is like : `{ "simplecounter": 2 }`

What I want is that I should be able to pass the `max` and `min` values for the counter in the reactive form html. And the form should return `form.valid` according to these `min` and `max` values.

It's giving the output values as expected but the validation is not working. After a lot of experimenting, still I'm not able to find any problem with the code.

Would greatly appreciated any help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of validation do you expect for control?

Comment: Basically I want a custom validation. I should be able to send the min and max values of the counter in the reactive form html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to define custom validator as a directive you have to register it properly:

```
{
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => SimpleCounterComponent),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
    instead of useValue
    ...
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9abz8n?file=src/app/simple-counter/simple-counter.component.ts)**